# Implementing the following RoundRobin scheduling code

Tags: c#, loops, round-robin

I have to make a Round Robin scheduler for a class. I initially created 3 `List<int>` lists to represent the process ids, their arrival time and their processing time. I sorted them by their arrival times. The processes are being assigned a fixed quantum (I've hard-coded that as 4) and now I want to apply RR on them and display the sequence order of each process & their remaining time in a `textBox` on a form.

I found one approach here, but it's in java:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544452/round-robin-cpu-scheduling-java-threads

I tried converting my three lists into object lists as shown in the link but basically, so far I've succeeded in creating a list of objects that represent processes. In each object, the `processname`, `arrivaltime`, `bursttime` are stored. This is represented by a class called `PCB`.

Now I've created a list in which to add a number of processes:

```
public List<pcb> list = new List<pcb>(); // In place of ArrayList used in the 
                                         // example code in the link.

//For loop runs in which above 3 parameters are assigned values & then they're 
// added to list:

PCB pcb = new PCB(processname1, arrivaltime1, bursttime1);
list.Add(pcb);
```

But how do I search through each value of the list in order to find an item and manipulate it? Say I want to access `bursttime` of `processname="P1"` and decrement it by 4?

Is this the wrong data structure for it in C#?

Comment: How do you need to "access" the values in the list? Do you want to iterate over the list, or get a value at a specific index?

Comment: I've also removed the `operating-system` tag, since I can't see any mention of operating systems in the question. Please feel free to re-insert it if I'm incorrect.

Comment: I want to iterate through the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// To access the value:
int bursttime1 = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.processname == "P1").bursttime;
// To change it:
list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.processname == "P1").bursttime -= 4;
```

If you prefer iterating through the list:

```
foreach (PCB pcb in list) {
    if (pcb.processname == "P1") {
        pcb.bursttime -= 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll check out the FirstorDefault method on msdn right now,Can you please explain what the variable x is declared as ?

Comment: `x` is the input parameter of the lambda expression `x => x.processname == "P1"`. To understand: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: by using FirstOrDefault, you open the possibility to return null, which is going to throw an exception at the time of accessing the bursttime property